# Wordpress RSS widget and Yahoo Pipes

Tags: widgets, rss, feed

My RSS widget seems to be having a mind of its own! I am using a yahoo pipe to combine multiple feeds into one feed. The output RSS is being fed into the RSS Widget. I have modified the pipe to have just one source connected to the output and give out just one item right now. But when I see the wordpress widget, I am getting multiple items from other sources too. When I click on the RSS icon, it displays the correct item. Help!

> Site: [www.consultbv.com](http://www.consultbv.com)
>
> Pipe RSS:
>   http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=5dc6250615570c48c68066bcaf97fa50&_render=rss

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason. It was because of the RSS Widget's Caching.